# What does a javascript symbol in brackets as an object key mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-redux

In the second file below I am trying to figure out what `[CALL_API]` is. What do the brackets mean? Is `[CALL_API]` the key for the object or is `[CALL_API]` resolved to something that is the actual key?  And what is the purpose of doing it this way instead of using the string "CALL_API" as the key?

```js
// file: middlewares/api.js

export const CALL_API = Symbol('CALL_API');

// (rest of file ommitted)
```

-

```js
import { CALL_API } from 'middlewares/api';

store.dispatch({
  [CALL_API]: {
    method: 'get',
    path: '/questions',
    sendingType: 'SENDING_QUESTIONS',
    successType: 'LOAD_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS',
  }
});
```

This code was from a react-redux app. More of the context can be seen is [this pluker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wA938F7gLbDSBmnbuzdU).

Comment: Symbols can be used as object keys. They don't resolve to strings. They're the only non-strings that can be used as keys.

Comment: its a new es6 thing where you can use a var for the key, much like we already did for values.

Comment: To clarify what needs answering - are you aware of exactly what `Symbol`s are?

Comment: I'm confused about symbols and why they are combined with the brackets.  The question was marked as a duplicate but I asked another because I don't understand how the brackets work specifically with symbols.  And when I tried an experiment it worked better without the brackets:   If I do `var bar = Symbol('bar')` then do `var foo = {[bar]: 99}`. When I try to use `foo.bar` it is undefined.  But if I don't use the brackets I get 99.